# Telerik iOS Chart matching Columns to axis

Tags: ios, telerik, ios8

I am using the Telerik UI for iOS 8 and since i haven't used anything like this before i am having a little trouble getting the column series to match to a specific Y axis.

Specifically :

```
TKChartCategoryAxis *categoryAxis = [[TKChartCategoryAxis alloc] initWithCategories:ArrayA];
_chartView.xAxis = categoryAxis;

TKChartNumericAxis *axisA = [[TKChartNumericAxis alloc]initWithMinimum:@0 andMaximum:@1000];
axisA.position = TKChartAxisPositionLeft;


TKChartNumericAxis *axisB = [[TKChartNumericAxis alloc]initWithMinimum:@0 andMaximum:@100];
axisB.position = TKChartAxisPositionRight;

TKChartColumnSeries *seriesA = [[TKChartColumnSeries alloc] initWithItems:ArrayB];
axisA.xAxis = categoryAxis;
seriesA.yAxis = axisA;

TKChartColumnSeries *seriesB = [[TKChartColumnSeries alloc] initWithItems:ArrayB];
axisB.xAxis = categoryAxis;
seriesB.yAxis = axisB;
```

I have tried editing to for each of the colums to match the y series, however these are being stacked one on top of another and not side by side like i need them. I dont know where i have gone wrong exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cluster series in TKChart only if all series share the same y axis. One option to solve the issue is to add another y axis that is not related with any of the series. Here is a sample:

```
TKChartCategoryAxis *xAxis = [[TKChartCategoryAxis alloc] initWithCategories:categories];
chart.xAxis = xAxis;

TKChartNumericAxis *leftAxis = [[TKChartNumericAxis alloc] initWithMinimum:@0 andMaximum:@1000];
leftAxis.position = TKChartAxisPositionLeft;
[chart addAxis:leftAxis];

TKChartNumericAxis *rightAxis = [[TKChartNumericAxis alloc] initWithMinimum:@0 andMaximum:@100];
rightAxis.position = TKChartAxisPositionRight;
[chart addAxis:rightAxis];

TKChartColumnSeries *seriesA = [[TKChartColumnSeries alloc] initWithItems:dataPoints];
TKChartColumnSeries *seriesB = [[TKChartColumnSeries alloc] initWithItems:dataPoints1];

[chart addSeries:seriesA];
[chart addSeries:seriesB];
```

Comment: Thank you, I also tried this but i was not sure if it was correct or not.